# Import Modules(pypsa)

Tags: pyscript, pypsa

I did it with pycript.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZOSC.png)
The following error occurs when running live server in vs code.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lDbf.png)

Answer (score 1):

As the error message details, **pypsa** does not have a pure Python 3 wheel available for installation.

Typically, that message means the Python package includes portions that are not written in Python, such as C or C++.

The package must be ported (converted) to work in the Pyodide/PyScript environment.